# Test if a TCP port is open without connecting to it

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-2.0, tcpclient

I've been asked to convert a bash script which uses `nc -z`, to PowerShell.

[This site](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/nc.htm) tells me that `nc -z` tests whether a port is open "without connecting to it".  Is there some way to do that using .Net?

### Additional Info

Normally to test if a port is open I'd .Net's `TcpClient` to create a connection; and if it connects I report all as well.  MVE below:

```powershell
$isConnected = $false
$client = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient'
try {
    $client.Connect($host, $port)
    $isConnected = $client.Connected
    $client.GetStream().Close(); # handle bug in .net 1.1
    $client.Close();
} catch {
    $isConnected = $false
} finally {
    if ($client.Dispose) {$client.Dispose()} # dispose method not available in all versions, so check before calling
}
```

However, whilst that sends no data, it does connect.

It could be that the description of `nc -z` is misleading / that it just means without sending data... I've not been able to find confirmation either way.

### Side node

Based on a couple of recent responses I'll point out that `Test-NetConnection` essentially uses the same `TcpClient` approach as mentioned above, so does "connect".  Also it's not available in PS2 / only comes into play in PSv4 in Windows 8 & above.  That said, it's worth a mention for anyone who doesn't have the unique requirements mentioned in this post.

Comment: "Not connecting" essentially means a port scan -- a TCP scan technically does connect, a SYN or FIN scan does not. Unless you go raw sockets I don't think you can do this directly from PowerShell, or even if you should. I'd just leverage `nmap` if you have a need for this (or, indeed, `nc` itself -- there are Windows ports, with varying levels of fidelity).

Comment: And, of course, the mere existence of an open TCP port in no way guarantees that whatever opened it is able to provide any meaningful services at this time.

Comment: *"It could be that the description of nc -z is misleading / that it just means without sending data"* Well, the article you linked literally says "without sending any data to them".

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert; I wasn't familiar with `FIN` / `SYN` / have found some good info here: https://www.varonis.com/blog/port-scanning-techniques/

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever fully agree - I'm just looking at doing a like-for-like for the current task, as don't have any real requirements to work to beyond "we want this, but in PS for Windows"... :/

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Agreed that it says it's not sending data... but it seems that the definition of `Connect` is variable (e.g. see info on not completing the TCP connect handshake here: https://www.varonis.com/blog/port-scanning-techniques/) - so there's room for assumption/error in their description.

Comment: If you are still looking for the answer to this, try using WSL like `bash -c "nc <address> <port> -z"`

Answer (score 1):

Using **Test-NetConnection**

```
Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $host -Port $port
```

Output looks like this:

```
ComputerName     : [computername]
RemoteAddress    : [remoteipaddress]
RemotePort       : 80
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet 2
SourceAddress    : [sourceipaddress]
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

[Test-NetConnection Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection?view=win10-ps)

Using Tcp Client Class (.Net):

```
 New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient($ip, $port)
```

Output:

```
Client              : System.Net.Sockets.Socket
Available           : 0
Connected           : True
ExclusiveAddressUse : False
ReceiveBufferSize   : 65536
SendBufferSize      : 64512
ReceiveTimeout      : 0
SendTimeout         : 0
LingerState         : System.Net.Sockets.LingerOption
NoDelay             : False
```

[Tcp Client Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks @RobotScience.  Those are good way to test if a port is open, but sadly both connect to the port to do so.  In over 99% of cases I suspect that's fine; but I was after a route which avoided this.  Some good info around this in the comments on the original question if you're interested in what's meant by "not connecting" at a more detailed level.